# CSS changer using PHP not working

Tags: php, html, css

Yo. I'm a beginner at PHP but I wanted to make a CSS changer for my website (tbex.info). I found a nice looking script on about.com which basically says I should put this in the head tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo (!$style)?'main':$style ?>.css" />
```

And then a form on the page that looks like this:

```
<form action="changestyle.php" method="post">
<select name="choice">
<option value="main" selected>Classic View</option>
<option value="small">Smaller (for smaller resolutions)</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

And then the form loads this script:

```
<?php 
  $Year =31536000 + time();
  setcookie('style', $_GET['choice'], $year);
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

I am currently working in Dreamweaver. When I typed all this up, the styling in Dreamweaver disappeared (as expected, since it's PHP) then I uploaded it to my server for beta tests. The code is supposed to load the default CSS and then when a user changes it by using the form, the PHP script is supposed to write a cookie and then reload the page. Then, the code in the head tags would read the cookie and change the CSS accordingly. So far, every SEEMS to have worked, other than the writing of cookies. I went into my browser setting (Google Chrome) and viewed all of my cookies. There was none that had come from my website. I've checked various forums and not found any real help. If anyone can help me fix this, or even help me write a CSS changing code (I'm looking for something a bit like the one on 4Chan.org), it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it **need** to be in a cookie? This can be done in a much easier way.

Comment: Yes, could you use session variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't **need** to use cookies, you can do this quite easily in a few different ways:

### 1. Use Session Variables

Have your form post to a page with code like this:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["css"] = $_POST["choice"];

?>
```

And then to retrieve it in your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["css"]))
        $style = $_SESSION["css"];
    else
        $style = "main";
    echo $style; ?>.css" />
```

### 2. Use $_GET Variables

Your form script:

```
<?php

    header("Location:".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."?css=".$_POST["choice"]);

?>
```

And then to access it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php
    $style = $_GET["css"];
    echo (!$style)?'main':$style ?>.css" />
```

---

### Some Clarification for a Beginner's Understanding:

Option #1 stores the string chosen in the form in what is called your "session." This is a short term variable maintained by your server during the user's activity period. Most servers have sessions set to expire after ~20 minutes of inactivity, but this can be changed to any number.

It should be noted that sessions **are innately cookies**, but PHP manages it for you, and all you need to do to access or change a variable in a session is `$_SESSION["var_name"]`. The great thing about sessions is that they are propagated to any PHP page on your website that implements `session_start();`. The not-so-great (in your case) aspect is that they are temporary, and will not remain on the user's device after an inactivity period.

---

When using $_GET variables, as in option #2, you are sending each page *individually* the variable. This is what you see when you get a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?someVar=blah
```

This provides your page `index.php` with a $_GET variable named "someVar" with a value of "blah." To retrieve this, you simply use `$_GET["someVar"]`. The great thing about this is that it can be sent and retrieved in a relatively easy fashion, through direct URLs or AJAX calls, but the bad thing is that it has to specified on every URL. **It is not automatically shared between all PHP pages**. In many cases this is a good thing, for instance, if you wanted to specify different CSS on each page or an ID number specific to each page, but in your case, this is not the easiest option to implement.

---

#### Therefore:

I would use session variables. They are easy to access, modify, and share between all pages.

Cookies are an animal to deal with. If I were you, I would stick to something more simple like this. If you need to store the choice over the long term, e.g. between sessions, I would use an SQL database to hold the data, rather than a cookie.

Comment: Hmmm, this seems to be close (option 2), thank you! The only issue I seem to have found is when swapping to the other CSS (small) it doesn't load the CSS at all :/

Comment: Check my edit of the script. Ternary operators are finicky; I would avoid them if at all possible.

Comment: I think I may have just found what could be the issue. Since I am a beginner, I thought the pages should be HTML (index.htm, for example). Now I realise I should probably have made them .php to run the script, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. PHP script is only run on pages with a php extension, e.g. `.php`, `.php5`, etc.

Comment: Ah! I feel so silly! At current I only have about six pages that I made in Dreamweaver by setting them up as HTML5. If I convert these files into PHP files, will I lose HTML5 support? In one page I have an audio file that plays as HTML5. The code is this:

<audio controls>
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=&amp;confirm=no_antivirus&amp;id=0B852lyIx5opMTGtpejZ0aEhGQ28" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>


So would that still work if it's a PHP file or not? I assume so as you can set up new PHP documents with HTML5.

Comment: Ah! I just tried out your first option on my new index.php page and it works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you. Oh and one more thing! It's not too much of a big deal but how can I get the CSS to be changed permanently using this PHP script? If you know at all :)

Comment: Wait, never mind, it was me being silly again! Haha, right I think this means it's time for bed! Seeya!

Answer (score 0):

This can be the script that the form loads.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['choice'] = $_GET['choice'];
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

And this can be your link.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo (!isset($_SESSION['choice']))?'main':$_SESSION['choice'] ?>.css" />
```

I also am a php beginner so just tell me if I made any mistakes in my answer.